# Rest Assured - How to pass object in "JSONObject body"

Tags: rest-assured

The below code when executed

```
public void RegistrationSuccessful()
{       
    RestAssured.baseURI ="http://restapi.demoqa.com/customer";
    RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();

    JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
    requestParams.put("FirstName", "Virender"); // Cast
    requestParams.put("LastName", "Singh");
    request.body(requestParams.toJSONString());
    Response response = request.post("/register");
}
```

returns

```
{
    "FirstName": "Virender",
    "LastName": "Singh"
}
```

Can someone please guide the rest assured code for the below JSON ?

```
{
    "FirstName": "Virender",
    "LastName": "Singh",
    "Address": {
        "Line1": "flat no 101",
        "area": "andheri",
        "City": "Mumbai"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use JSONObject, HashMap, or a POJO for this

A sample code using **JSONObject**, I haven't tested the below code so let me know if it doesn't work

```
JSONObject requestparams = new JSONObject();
JSONArray authArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject authparam = new JSONObject();

    requestParams.put("FirstName", "Virender");
    requestParams.put("LastName", "Singh");

        authparam.put("Line1", "Flat no 101");
        authparam.put("Area", "Andheri");
        authparam.put("City", "Mumbai");
        authArray.add(authparam);

        requestparams.put("Address", authparam);

    req.body(requestparams.toJSONString());
    Response response = req.post("http://restapi.demoqa.com/customer/register");
```

Also a sample using **HashMap**

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("FirstName", "Virender");
map.put("LastName", "Singh");
map.put("Address", Arrays.asList(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
    put("Line1", "Flat no 101");
    put("Area", "Andheri");
    put("City", "Mumbai");
}}
));

RequestSpecification req=RestAssured.given();
req.header("Content-Type","application/json");
req.body(map).when();
Response resp = req.post("http://restapi.demoqa.com/customer/register");
```

Answer (score 0):

The practical way to handle nested json is to serialize the json by a POJO. The POJO for the given json would be: [Here I am using gson]

```
public class Address {

@SerializedName("Line1")
@Expose
private String line1;
@SerializedName("area")
@Expose
private String area;
@SerializedName("City")
@Expose
private String city;

public String getLine1() {
return line1;
}

public void setLine1(String line1) {
this.line1 = line1;
}

public String getArea() {
return area;
}

public void setArea(String area) {
this.area = area;
}

public String getCity() {
return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
this.city = city;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("FirstName")
@Expose
private String firstName;
@SerializedName("LastName")
@Expose
private String lastName;
@SerializedName("Address")
@Expose
private Address address;

public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Address getAddress() {
return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
this.address = address;
}

}
```

Now when you want to create the payload, just construct the object of Example class and pass the same to the test method.

```
Example  example = new Example(
        "Virender", "Singh", new Address("Line1", "flat no 101", "andheri", "Mumbai")
        );

public void RegistrationSuccessful(Example example){
    // Method definition
    RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
    request.body(example);
    Response _response = _request.post("//EndPoint");
}
```

In this way, you can handle much more complex payload. More over all the POJO can be generated from the json.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage org.json external library to achieve this.
Create object of JSONObject like this -

```
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();

jsonobj.put("FirstName","Virender");
jsonobj.put("LastName","Singh");

// Create another json object for address

JSONObject jsonobj1 = new JSONObject();
jsonobj1.put("Line1","flat no 101");
jsonobj1.put("area","andheri");
jsonobj1.put("City","Mumbai");

jsonobj.put("Address", jsonobj1);
Response response = RestAssured.given()
            .log().all()
            .header("Content-Type", ContentType.JSON)
            .body(jsonobj.toString())
            .post("");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).